# Show when div got select or option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an application with info page and edit page
the info page shows the info.
in the edit page i have fields with selectbox etc etc

I want to use same code for both. So I tried

```
if($('#product').has('option'))
{
    console.log('hasSelect')
}
else{
    console.log('NOSELECTNO')
    }
```

in single page there is no option or select avaible 
but in the edit it is.

How can I make sure it will work (and why is this not working)

edit tried this 2:

```
var attr = $('#product div').attr('select');

if (typeof attr !== typeof undefined && attr !== false) {
    console.log("welmetselect")
}
else
{
    console.log("zonderselect")
}
```

EDIT: HTML

```
<div id= product>
    <div>some more divs</div>
    <div> in 1 of the div we have <select><option></option></select></div>
</div>
```

And html infopage

```
<div id= product>
    <div>only information</div>
    <div>only text </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us some HTML? I don't quite get it yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
if ($("#product option").length )
```

If you don't have an option, the length will be 0 (and therefore false)

Comment: THNX THIS WORKED FOR ME

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you could just give them different IDs, or a class like `.info` and `.edit`, and simply check `$('#product').hasClass('info')`. I do not recommend checking for a specific descendant to identify an element anyway, because you want your code to be as flexible as it can be, and if you decide to add a select element to your info page in the future, for example, to filter out specific items to get info on, your code totally breaks.

Second, why your code is not working, is this.

```
var attr = $('#product div').attr('select');
```

`select` is not an attribute, it's a child. Use `children('select')` (if it's a direct child) or `find('select')` (if it's not a direct child).

As a sidenote, you can simplify `typeof attr !== typeof undefined` to `typeof attr !== 'undefined'` because we already know `typeof undefined` is returning `'undefined'`.

Comment: THNX FOR YOUR TIME